# How to write a Trigger based on row update

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am first time using a trigger, Now I am facing some problems,

I have 3 tables, InvoiceHead, InvoiceDetails, InventoryMaster .

when I update 'Status' field of InvoiceHead (from 0 to 1), 'Status' fields of InvoiceDetails and InventoryMaster need to be changed based on the updated row.

Reltionships :
InvoiceHead_id=InvoiceDetails_id (FK) and
InventoryMaster_Processid=InvoiceHead_id  (FK)

How can write a trigger in InvoiceHead ?

Please help to solve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
create trigger your_trigger
on InvoiceHead
after update
as
//declare @status int;
//select @status=i.status from inserted i;  
//IF @status == 1 
//BEGIN

update d
set d.status = b.status
from InvoiceDetails as d
join inserted as b 
on a.InvoiceDetails_id = b.InvoiceHead_id
where b.status == 1; 

update m
set m.status = b.status
from InventoryMaster  as m
join inserted as b 
on m.InventoryMaster_Processid = b.InvoiceHead_id
where b.status == 1;


end
go
```

But keep in mind that in SQL trigger works on entire update not like rowwise in oracle. so if this trigger will fire for more than one row at a time my code won't work for your requirement..You need to fine tune it..

Comment: Thank you friend, This works fine, and can you clear me if you are not busy, what you have mentioned abt entire rowwise update issue of SQL compared to oracle ?  I think my trigger now working perfectly in row based update, its in sqlserver 2008

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @status=i.status from inserted i;` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get one arbitrary row, and you'll **ignore** all the others. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: @marc_s yes what you said is correct..thats what i mentioned in last statement..In sql trigger work for entire update statement if 25 update happened this trigger will fire at once for 25 not row by row like in oracle..Thats what i asked him to take care off

Comment: But the code that **you posted** does **not** take care of that! That's what I'm saying - you *say* you have to be careful about this - yet your own code violates this advice.....

Comment: @AmjadhNm in oracle if a trigger is wrote for an update or insert it will fire for row by row case. But in sql it is not the case. The trigger will execute for entire update at once see marc_s comment..if this answer helped you just upvote..

Comment: @marc_s yup..i just given him a guideline...if you can just edit it for take care of the same..thanks

Comment: @marc_s thanks for your comment..i updated my answer can you pls tell me any issue in this..even i learned a new thing today thanks!!\

Comment: @Sachu,@marc_s..Thank you very much for yours consideration and explanation. I got clear, I'm trying to learn abt this more..

Comment: Now it should work just fine, even if your `UPDATE` statement affects more than a single row

Comment: @AmjadhNm just try my edited answer..i take consider the situation marc explained..just check and tell..if helped mark it and vote..thanks

Comment: @Sachu  Thank you very much, I really appreciate all your help and answer, you guys are brilliant. I didnt think much more about it, sorry for the late comment , Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @marc_s..Thank you very much for all support

Comment: @AmjadhNm glad to hear it helped :)